# Code generation for default interface methods (in IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, default-implementation

Before JDK 8 I would write: `A implements B` and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to automatically generate the method headers for the methods in `B` so I only have to fill in the method bodies.

However in JDK 8 it is possible that `B` provides a `default` implementation and this doesn't work anymore.

How can I still generate the code in this case?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.

Comment: have you tried ALT+Insert --> Implement Methods / Override Methods?

Comment: @damo That works! Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is just a shortcut to bring up IDEA's [suggested solutions](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intention-actions.html). In your case, it's just a quick way to get to `Code|Implement Methods...` or `Code|Override Methods...`

You can also get to these menus via the Generate menu: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

Or directly via their respective keymaps: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>(override) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>(implement)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are on OSX you can use <kbd>Ctrl ^</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>. There you'll have all the default methods available to implement from the interfaces defined in your class.
[image: Methods available when implement WebMvcConfigurer in IntelliJ IDEA]